# How to make a bot reply to an emoji?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying this for the last two hours. I am trying to get my bot to say "HE TAKES THE SHOT" after I do an emoji of a ping pong bat. I've been trying to store the emoji into a const but it says ReferenceError: client is not defined
Please help, ty in advance

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const token = 'token';

const PREFIX = '!';

var bat = ('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FZzQGSBHdyk/maxresdefault.jpg');


const bat1 = client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "bat1");

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', message =>{
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    
    switch(args[0]){
        
        case 'ping':
            message.channel.send('pong')
        break;
        
        case 'info':
            message.channel.send('PingPongBot is a project Eefan and sc0rps is working on, which hopefully will turn into a fully playable discord game! PingPongBot will also have some helpers, the one we have so far is Bananaprey!')
        break;
        
        case 'bat':
            message.channel.send(bat)
        break;
    }
})  
    

bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if(msg.content === bat1){
        msg.reply('HE TAKES THE SHOT');
    }
})  

    
bot.login(token);
```

Comment: ive understand that i need to replace client with bot but still doesnt work

Comment: It says this now TypeError: bot.emojis.find is not a function

Comment: It's `bot.emojis.cache.find()`

Comment: Even then still doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch the emoji **before** the Discord client has had a chance to initialise and login, hence unable to access the emojis.

Assuming you're running on Discord.js v12, the code below should work:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const token = 'token';

const PREFIX = '!';

var bat = ('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FZzQGSBHdyk/maxresdefault.jpg');

// Initialise bat1 as an empty variable
let bat1;

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    // After the client has logged in, forward the emoji to bat1
    bat1 = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "bat1");

    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', message =>{
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    
    switch(args[0]){
        
        case 'ping':
            message.channel.send('pong')
        break;
        
        case 'info':
            message.channel.send('PingPongBot is a project Eefan and sc0rps is working on, which hopefully will turn into a fully playable discord game! PingPongBot will also have some helpers, the one we have so far is Bananaprey!')
        break;
        
        case 'bat':
            message.channel.send(bat)
        break;
    }
})  
    

bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if(msg.content === bat1){
        msg.reply('HE TAKES THE SHOT');
    }
})  

    
bot.login(token);
```

If you are using v11, it should be `bot.emojis.find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change client to bot in your  code:

```
const bat1 = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "bat1");
```

This should work :))